# How to wait for elements to be created with async-await?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

hope you all are having a good day.

I try to make `fillClassData()` wait for `createClassElementsWith()`. I figured I have to use async await and return a promise, data somehow to make it work. Any ideas how to solve this in a clean readable way? What would I return?

Code:

```
// get data
async function fillClassData() {
  const prop_id = prop_select.children('option:selected').val();
  const selected_class = config.getClass();
  // fetch data
  const data = await api.fetchClass(prop_id);

  // create options
  await createClassElementsWith(data);

  if (itemsExist(selected_class)) {
    class_select.val(selected_class);
    // fill table info
    fillTableData();
  }
}

// creates options for classes
async function createClassElementsWith(data) {
  // clear options
  class_select.find('option').remove();
  // create new options per entry
  if (data.length <= 0) {
    generateOption('default', 'No options yet', class_select);
  } else {
    generateOption('default', 'Select Class...', class_select);
    for (let item of data) {
      generateOption(item.class_id, item.class_name, class_select);
    }
  }
  class_select.children('option')[0].selected = true;
}

// creates element with given parameters
function generateOption(value, text, select) {
  // create element
  let opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = value;
  opt.innerHTML = text;
  // set some options to disabled
  if(value === 'default') opt.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  // append to select
  select.append(opt);
}
```

data example:

```
class_id: "3179807"
class_longname: "long class name"
class_name: "short class name"
```

Btw. the function `fillClassData()` is called based on a select option of a `prop`. The function `fillTableData()` fills in a table with the data gotten based on those two selects.

Comment: `createClassElementsWith` doesn't look like it needs to be async?

Comment: yeah right, I thought so too but then I can't await the function? err: 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression @evolutionxbox

Comment: You can await the function, it just doesn't do anything. `await (() => 'hi')() // 'hi'`

Comment: Right. But to select existing selections, the options have to already exist. How do I wait for the elements to be created? @evolutionxbox

Comment: The creation will be synchronous. unless `generateOption` fetches data?

Comment: Sadly it does not... is there no way to make it async if it just creates elements and appends those? @evolutionxbox

Comment: There's no need to make it async? The code executed after it will wait regardless

Comment: Well yeah, should in my eyes too. For some reason when I log seemingly already created options, they are undefined. Which means the option can't be selected and the parameter which is used to fetch data will also be undefined. @evolutionxbox
edit: the options are available for the selection afterwards

Comment: May you share `generateOption`? And is `data` not undefined?

Comment: I added it. ```data``` is not empty. If ```data``` was empty it wouldn't continue because of ```if(data.length <= 0)``` @evolutionxbox

Comment: May you share an example of `data`? It would be helpful

Comment: This should be straightforward. Throw away jquery, all those functions and all those test conditions , declare your statments line by line. When your logic is okay, factorize, add more logic, handle possible errors. But only then.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I figured it out!

Comment: @Nati what happened? May you share it as an answer?

Comment: I already did ;) @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Big thanks to the people commenting and trying to help but the problem was somewhere completely else. I guess my debugging skills are not the greatest and I started looking at the wrong end.

I saved selected options in the local storage but I didn't clear the saved class whenever a new `prop` was selected. Which means the data can't be fetched correctly, the parameters don't match up. I added a function to my config now: `config.clearClass();` which clears the class item in the localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite workaround for something like this is to add a `setTimeout()`. The delay can be 1 ms or 5ms, whichever seems more dependable to you. Put all of the code that depends on `createClassElementsWith` in the timeout.

```
// get data
async function fillClassData() {
  const prop_id = prop_select.children('option:selected').val();
  const selected_class = config.getClass();
  // fetch data
  const data = await api.fetchClass(prop_id);

  // create options
  createClassElementsWith(data); // Nothing to wait for like evolutionxbox said

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (itemsExist(selected_class)) {
      class_select.val(selected_class);
      // fill table info
      fillTableData();
    }
  }, 1); // 1 ms should be enough time for createClassElements to run
}

// creates options for classes
function createClassElementsWith(data) {
  // clear options
  class_select.find('option').remove();
  // create new options per entry
  if (data.length <= 0) {
    generateOption('default', 'No options yet', class_select);
  } else {
    generateOption('default', 'Select Class...', class_select);
    for (let item of data) {
      generateOption(item.class_id, item.class_name, class_select);
    }
  }
  class_select.children('option')[0].selected = true;
}

// creates element with given parameters
function generateOption(value, text, select) {
  // create element
  let opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = value;
  opt.innerHTML = text;
  // set some options to disabled
  if(value === 'default') opt.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  // append to select
  select.append(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The word async has one simple meaning: this function always returns a promise. Other types of values ​​are automatically wrapped in a successful promise.

`async function f() { return 1; }`

You can explicitly return a promise, the result will be the same:

```
async function f() {
```

return Promise.resolve(1);
}

```
f().then(alert); // 1
```

The await keyword will cause the JavaScript interpreter to wait until the promise to the right of await is executed. After which it will return its result, and the code execution will continue.
// Works only inside async functions

```
let value = await promise;

enter code here
```